# Is this app Icon Browser Safe/Legit?

Tags: 18.04

I just noticed this app in my ubuntu applications called Icon Browser.

[image]

I want to know if it's legit part of Ubuntu or could it be malware using it to disguise itself of other code.

In other words if it is a part of normal ubuntu package and if not how I can remove it.

### Additional Info

Here's the output of searching for the app in apt

```
$ apt list icon* --installed
Listing... Done
```

Comment: It does not seem to be part of the standard Ubuntu repositories, or at least I cannot `apt search icon` and find anything that looks like it.  Please append your question with the output of `apt list icon* --installed`

Comment: K - As far as I can tell, this was not installed using the `apt` system, and not from the standard repositories, or an added PPA (which may or may not be trustworthy).  Minor Google searches ("icon browser ubuntu") don't turn up anything like this - so *someone* installed this program. I don't like programs that I cannot trace back to a source.  Can you right click on the icon, click "Show Details", and see if there is any identifying information about the program?  Also look at the desktop file for the program, which *should be* in `/usr/share/applications` to see what command it is calling.

Comment: `grep -Rl 'Icon Browser' /usr/share/applications`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found it!  It's an application called "Yad".  As this is in the repositories, it has been checked by the good people at canonical and can probably be trusted.

[image]

Comment: [Here's the .desktop file in upstream](https://github.com/v1cont/yad/blob/b3a990431b960ca7d538662545982fd2f5d7479d/data/yad-icon-browser.desktop.in)

Answer (score 4):

There is an "Icon Browser" GUI utility (`gtk3-icon-browser`) comes from the `gtk-3-examples` package. If you have the same thing, then it should be fine.

To check it, first run the following command to find out whether `gtk-3-examples` is installed:

```
apt policy gtk-3-examples
```

If it's installed, run

```
gtk3-icon-browser
```

to launch the application. Associated `.desktop` launcher, viz. `gtk3-icon-browser.desktop` [should be found](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gtk-3-examples/filelist) in the `/usr/share/applications/` directory.

Comment: I just installed `gtk-3-examples` but it does not seem to create a desktop file, or the icon shown in the OP's question - I suspect that these are not the same thing!

Comment: @Charles Really?! `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i icon` doesn't list anything? As per [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gtk-3-examples/filelist) there should be a `gtk3-icon-browser.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` (for Bionic at least).

Comment: Ayuh - there's a desktop file, but the application itself does not show in the 'activities' window.  Of course I have been poking at my system a lot, and something may be broken.

Comment: It turns out to be the application named "Yad"

Comment: @CharlesGreen No, you're right. There is a `NoDisplay=true` line in the `.desktop` file. To make it visible, one needs to remove the line or change `true` to `false` or make a working copy in local directory first.